# How to remove some records from query in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

there are 3 tables

1. posts
2. postTags
3. roles

each post have some tags and each user have some roles

all users can see public posts and 
just users who have roles can see posts that have these roles-title in post-tags-title

I need to remove some records from a query
.

```
// hasRole mean Only visible to users who have role
$allPosts = Post::where('type', 'public')
    ->orWhere('type', 'hasRole')
    ->get();

// all user roles
$allUserRoles = Role::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->select('roleTitle')->get();

foreach ($allPosts as $post)
{
    if($post->type == 'hasRole')
    {
        // just visible this post to anyOne who have these role
        $allPostTags = Tag::where('post_id', $post->id)->select('tagTitle')->get();

        // $subscribe between postTags and userRoles
        $subscribe = array_intersect($allPostTags, $allUserRoles);

        if (count($subscribe) < 1) {
            // remove this record from $allPosts
            // ???
        }
    }
}
return $allPosts->take(10);
```

Can I get all the posts that are public once, then combine them with posts that have specific access, then order posts by date?

Is there an easier way?